# How to set index of data frame using list in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary using that i am forming a dataframe.
I have list which i want to set it as an index.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {'animal': ['cat', 'cat', 'snake', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog'],
        'age': [2.5, 3, 0.5, np.nan, 5, 2, 4.5, np.nan, 7, 3],
        'visits': [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1],
        'priority': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no']}
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(labels)
```

I am receiving KeyError: 'a' as an error.

Comment: Use `df.index = labels`?

Comment: or `df.set_index([labels])` or `df.set_axis(labels,inplace=True)`

Comment: got it bro..Thanks